# Custom Progress Dialog hides the soft keyboard android

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard, progressdialog

**Query Description:** I am using custom progress dialog with the transparent theme. And this works fine. What problem I am facing is, when my keyboard is open and if I show Custom Progress Dialog then *It force closes my Keyboard.* However, if I use default Progress Dialog then it works fine.

[image: Here is Default Progress Dialog]: As you can see the keyboard is still there even after progress dialog appears. **I want to implement the same in Custom Progress Dialog.**

[image: Here is Custom Progress Dialog]: As you can see, the keyboard gets disappears when the dialog is showing. It feels tedious, every time the user has to open the keyboard.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends Dialog {
private ImageView imageView;
private Context mContext;

public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
    mContext = context;
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
    setTitle(null);
    setCancelable(true);
    //setOnCancelListener(null);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_dialog);
    layout.addView(imageView, params);
    addContentView(layout, params);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
}
}
```

**Dialog theme in style.xml:**

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/actionbar_gradient_endColor</item>
</style>
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/et_search_category" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgClearSearch" 
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rdt_txt" 
    android:hint="Search here..." 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb: there is not any IME option I have set in manifest.

And for Edittext here it is:

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgClearSearch"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rdt_txt"
            android:hint="Search here..."
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

Comment: No worries @YvetteColomb. Thanks for your valuable time. :)

Comment: Try this : CustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I come up with the solution:

I saw Default Progress Dialog extends `AlertDialog`. However, in my code, I was extending `Dialog` class.

Now I am extending `ProgressDialog` instead of `Dialog` and this works like a charm.

**Here is the code:**

```
public class MyCustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {
private ImageView imageView;

public MyCustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
    setTitle(null);
    setCancelable(false);
    setOnCancelListener(null);

}

public MyCustomProgressDialog(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_custom_progress_dialog);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.centerImage);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_dialog);

}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
}
}
```

**Layout File:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/centerImage"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**style.xml:**

```
<style name="TransparentProgressDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**How to call?:**

```
ProgessDialog mProgressDialog = new MyCustomProgressDialog(this);
mProgressDialog.show(); //to show
mProgressDialog.dismiss(); //to dismiss
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.know about that whether soft keyboard is showing or not .
>
> 2.show or hide soft keyboard

Try this .

```
private Context context;
private boolean isShow = false;

// soft keyboard is show or not
private boolean isSoftShowing() {
    // screen height
    int screenHeight = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

    return screenHeight - rect.bottom - getSoftButtonsBarHeight() != 0;
}

private int getSoftButtonsBarHeight() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    // screen height ,not include navigation
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    // real screen height
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    if (realHeight > usableHeight) {
        return realHeight - usableHeight;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    // hideSoftKeyboard
    if(isSoftShowing()){
        ((Activity)context).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        isShow = true;
    }
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
    if(isShow){
        ((Activity)context).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will open the keyboard after every dismiss. In entire project :(

Comment: I want it to remain as it is. If it is visible before progress dialog then it should remain visible.

If it is invisible before showing the progress dialog then it should remain invisible. i.e UnChanged in all the cases.

Comment: I got it .I will try another way

Comment: You can check it again.

Comment: Hey, I come up with the solution. Please check my answer.
And thank you so much as you have invested your valuable time. I appreciate you :) Thanks!